# Add all the shapefile in a map from a folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'd like to know how can I add, in the map, all the shapefile which are in a specific folder, in one shot; using an algorithm of the Graphical Modeler of QGIS (if it exists). I noticed a similar algorithm, but it can only add a single shapefile.
I need this function using the graphical modeler and it should be a part of a complex model.

Comment: Have you tried to give the path to folder as input? Al least GDAL supports that and reports individual shapefiles as layers as you can test with `ogrinfo path_to_folder`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a QGIS plugin [Load Them All](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/loadthemall/). However, it probably won't work in the Graphic Modeler.

But you can use batch processing for loading data. Let's say you have a very simple Model: load shapefiles, create buffer, safe. When you run the model, select `Run as Batch Process…`:

[image]

You can then select which files should be selected: `Autofill… / Add Files by Pattern…` and add `*.shp` to load all Shapefiles in the selected folder. There are many other possibilities to define complex patterns which file(s) should be loaded, including QGIS expressions.

*Remark: The same for the output: I used an expression like `'C:\\[my_path]\\buffer\\'  ||  @row_number  || '.gpkg'` to save the outputs named 0.gpkg, 1.gpkg etc. to the same folder. The double backslashes `\\` are necessary to mask the single backslash `\` (working on Windows, paths might be different on other operating systems).*

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks!! It works! Suppose that, there are 10 .shp in a folder and i want to create a buffer only for 1 and the remaining 9 should be only load in the map. All using the Model. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. First create the buffer for one file, than run a batch process to open the other ones. Define a criteria for the filename that includes all but the file you created the buffer. Or open also this file again - it will probably do no harm, would it?

Comment: Ok. I'm running a batch process and i have a column set with the 1 layer for the buffer, a column set with the 9 layers to load and a column set for the output. It creates 10 buffers of the 1 layer but the 9 layers are not shown in the map. What's wrong?